# i'm trying to create a product and save to database but isn't working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to create a product and save it.
The page redirects where it's supposed to but doesn't save the date.
recently I  had some problem registering a user and when I fixed it now this problem occurred.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from .models import myUser,Listings,Bid
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .form import registerForm,loginForm,createListingForm
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        message = f"please sign in"
    else :
        message = f"signed in as {request.user}"
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html",{
        "listings": Listings.objects.all(),
        "message": message
    })

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = loginForm()
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request,username=email,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/login.html",{
                "form": form ,
                "message": "username/password not valid"
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/login.html",{
        "form": loginForm()
    })

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = registerForm()
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # check passwords are same
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]

        if password != confirmation:
            return render (request, "auctions/register.html",{
                "form": form,
                "message": "Passwords does not match"
            })
        
        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = myUser.objects.create_user(email,password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
                "form":form,
                "message": "Username is already taken"
            })

        login(request,user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    return render(request, "auctions/register.html", {
        "form": registerForm()
    })

@login_required(login_url='login')
def createListing(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = createListingForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.listed_by = request.user
            obj.save()
            # messages.success(request,"Creation successful")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = createListingForm()

    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "form": form
        })


def itemPage(request,listing_id):
    return render(request, "auctions/item.html", {
        "item" : Listings.objects.get(pk= listing_id)
    })

@login_required(login_url='login')
def bid(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_bid = request.POST["new_bid"]

    return HttpResponseRedirect('itemPage')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class myUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    custom user model manager where email is unique indentifiers for authenticaton
    instead of usernames.
    """

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active',True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff= True'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email,password, **extra_fields)

class myUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = myUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email}'

class Listings(models.Model):
    listing_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date_listed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    item_image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, default="Description Not Available")
    listed_by = models.ForeignKey(myUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.listing_name}'


class Bid(models.Model):
    item_name = models.ForeignKey(Listings,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bid_by_user = models.ForeignKey(myUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_bid = models.IntegerField()
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.forms import Form,PasswordInput
from .models import Listings,myUser
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = myUser
        
        fields = ['email', 'password']

        widgets = {
            # telling Django your password field in the mode is a password input on the template
            'password': forms.PasswordInput()
        }

class registerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirmation = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = myUser

        fields = ['email', 'password']

        widgets = {
            
                # telling Django your password field in the mode is a password input on the template
                'password': forms.PasswordInput()
            
        }

class createListingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Listings

        fields = ['listing_name', 'price', 'item_image', 'description']
```

create.html

```
{% extends 'auctions/layout.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

    <div>
        <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </div>

{% endblock%}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('create_listing/', views.createListing, name='create'),
    path('item/<int:listing_id>', views.itemPage, name='item'),
    path('bid/', views.bid, name='bid')
]
```

I would also like to request some other suggestions on my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are uploading any files, use `multipart/form-data` when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.

Currently, when you are submitting the form, the form is invalid since it does not contain the `multipart/form-data` in the create.html file. Hence, it is not getting saved.

Replace
`<form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">`
with

```
<form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, if the answer worked for you, then accept the solution (by clicking on the tick mark) so that others can find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about creating a listing. Can you try this way instead?

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createListing(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = createListingForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            listing_name = form.cleaned_data.get("listing_name")
            price = form.cleaned_data.get("price")
    
            # get the image from the form 
            item_image = request.FILES['item_image']

            description = form.cleaned_data.get("description")
            listed_by = request.user
            
            # here is where the saving happens
            Listings.objects.create_user(
                  listing_name=listing_name,
                  price=price,
                  item_image=item_image,
                  description=description,
                  listed_by=listed_by)

            # then do your redirections or whatever you want done after save

            # messages.success(request,"Creation successful")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = createListingForm()

    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "form": form
        })
```

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't show any error. after submitting page redirects to the index page but data isn't saved.